# PowerShell dot reference XML attribute

Tags: xml, powershell, attributes

Given a single XML node like this

```
<MachineLogFileName overwrite="[bool]"></MachineLogFileName>
```

and assigned to a variable like this

```
$validationNode = $validation.xml.SelectSingleNode("//Settings/$($node.name)")
```

where of course `$node.name` is `'MachineLogFileName'`, and a variable `$attribute.name` of `'overwrite'`, I want to be able to get the value of that attribute, but only as an attribute. I can use `$validationNode.($attribute.name)`, but IF there was a child node called `<overwrite>` 
and wasn't an attribute called `'overwrite'` I would end up getting the inner text of the child node. So in a sense I want something like `$validationNode.Attributes.($attribute.name)`. It seems like there is a collection there, with a single attribute in this case, but I can't seem to get the value this way. Ultimately this needs to work with highly variable attribute and child node names, and I could just loop through all the attributes, but I need this in an IF so something like `$validationNode.Attributes.($attribute.name)` would be ideal. And seems like it should be possible and I am just missing one aspect? I hope.

Comment: Please share a more detailed [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to get the value of that attribute, but only as an attribute. I can use `$validationNode.($attribute.name)`, but IF there was a child node called `<overwrite>` and wasn't an attribute called 'overwrite'

Use [`GetAttribute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.getattribute):

```bsh
$validationNode = $validation.xml.SelectSingleNode("//Settings/$($node.name)")
$attributeValue = $validationNode.GetAttribute($attribute.name)
```